# Can you access the objects in a struct from outside the struct?

Tags: hstack

Can you access the objects in a struct from outside the struct?

So far I have a group of HStacks and VStacks whose embedded objects are all Images(“name”).

By definition these Images are fixed in terms of their .position and .size for example.

Can I dynamically access these embedded objects from outside the struct?

**In short, move them?**

**.. or include a Node so I could change its color?**

All changes made from Swift **outside** the struct?